# Getting date from firebase in flutter and store it in a var

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

Is there a way I can get data from firebase and store it as string for example in flutter?

I want my app to have role based users each user has a role and a page for them.
firebase authentication only has username and password. in my database I have Users collection the UID is used as an ID for the documents, I want to query the document and get the role value and store it in a variable as string.
http://prntscr.com/kwcylt

```
 Container(
              height: 50.0,
              child: Material(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                shadowColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                color: Colors.green,
                elevation: 7.0,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    FirebaseAuth.instance
                        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                          email: email,
                          password: password)
                        .then((FirebaseUser user) {
                         var userRole = Firestore.instance.collection('Users').document(user.uid).toString();

                         if(userRole['Role'].toString().compareTo("Admin"))
                            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/AdminTabs');
                          else Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/UserTabs');      
                    })
                        .catchError((e) {
                          print(e);
                    });
                  },
```

I want userRole Contain data from firebase

Comment: I tried Future and StreamBuild but they gave me "instance_of_Future"

Comment: Please post your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Your Code like this , it will Work: You are Basically Running the Check on Document Reference instead of Document Snapshot.

```
.then((FirebaseUser user) {
    Firestore.instance.collection('Users')
                .document('user.uid').get().then((userRole){
              if(userRole['Role'].toString().contains("Admin")){
                 Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/AdminTabs');
              }
    else {Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/UserTabs');}
            });

                    })
                        .catchError((e) {
                          print(e);
                    });
                  },
```